SQL Server Authentication Issues in Visual Studio SSAS 2022 Project
I’m currently working on a project in Visual Studio involving SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) 2022 and I'm encountering persistent authentication issues. My project involves working with the Wide World Importers database. Here’s a detailed description of my setup and the problem I’m facing:
Setup:
**SQL Server Version:** SQL Server 2019
**SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) Version:** SSMS 2022
**Database:** WideWorldImportersDW
**Visual Studio Version:** Visual Studio 2019

Problem Description:
When I try to create a new named query on the Invoice table within Visual Studio, I repeatedly get a prompt asking for a user ID and password. I am using the sa account with SQL Server authentication, and these credentials work perfectly fine when logging into SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).
Steps Taken So Far:
Connection String Verification:
Updated the connection string to explicitly include User ID=sa and the password:

Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=MSI\MYSQL2024MD;Initial Catalog=WideWorldImportersDW;User ID=sa;Password=my_password;

Impersonation Settings:
Set the impersonation option to use the credentials of the current user.
Permissions:
Verified that the sa user has db_owner and db_datareader roles on the WideWorldImportersDW database.
Executed the following script to grant necessary permissions:


    USE WideWorldImportersDW;
    GO
    GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::dbo TO sa;
    GO

Connection Testing:
Tested the connection in Visual Studio using the same SQL Server authentication (sa account) and it was successful:
Connection string used:
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=MSI\MYSQL2024MD;Initial Catalog=WideWorldImportersDW;User ID=sa;Password=my_password;

 The test connection was successful using SQL Server authentication.

Issue Encountered:
Despite the successful connection test, when I try to create a named query on the Invoice table, I get a prompt asking for a user ID and password. I use the same sa login information that was used to test the connection, but it does not work. I’ve tried several variations but keep encountering the same issue.

Screenshots:
Here are some screenshots for reference:
Log in properties for sa

security > logins
login properties
server roles user mapping

Error Prompt in Visual Studio

log in prompt error

Questions:
1.- Why does Visual Studio keep prompting me for the user ID and password even though they are correct and work in SSMS?
2.- Is there a specific setting or configuration I might be missing that could resolve this issue?
3.- Are there any known issues or bugs related to SSAS 2022 and Visual Studio that I should be aware of?
I’ve tried looking for solutions, including using ChatGPT, but haven't found a resolution. Any help or insights you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!
This is a list of the solutions I have tried:

Verified Login Credentials:


Confirmed that the sa user and password are correct by logging into SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) with those credentials.


Checked and Updated Connection Strings:


Ensured the connection string in Visual Studio includes the correct User ID and Password for the sa account.


Impersonation Issues:


Addressed impersonation issues by ensuring the SSAS service account has the necessary permissions in the database.


SQL Server Configuration:


Verified that the sa account has the db_owner role and necessary permissions for the WideWorldImportersDW database.


Database Source Configuration in Visual Studio:


Checked and tried different configurations for the data source in Visual Studio, including using SQL Server authentication and the same credentials as SSMS.


Service Account Permissions:


Attempted to add the SSAS service account to the WideWorldImportersDW database with db_datareader role permissions to ensure it can access the data.

Despite these efforts, you continue to encounter the prompt for user ID and password when creating a named query in Visual Studio.

Do you have other drivers you can use? SQLNCLI11 hasn't been updated since SQL Server 2012 days and isn't even shipped any more as of SQL Server 2022.

Because the book I am following prompted me to explicitly use that one. Would I run into any log in issues or project wise? or do I have to start all over again? The book I am using is called "Steven Hughes - Hands-On SQL Server 2019 Analysis Services"
